# Does adding a second IP as /32 with static routing cause any unintended issues?

Tags: networking, router, routing, ip-address, subnet

I have a /28 network and I’d like to add a single IP (/32 network). On my Debian machine this looks like:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static 
  address 192.0.2.212/28
  gateway 192.0.2.209
iface eth0 inet static
  address 192.0.2.175/32
```

Then, on the router (192.0.2.209/28) I have a static route: “route 192.0.2.175/32 next-hop 192.0.2.212”

Is there anything wrong with this approach ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's a fairly normal configuration.

(The address doesn't necessarily need to be on eth0, as the router will not make ARP queries for it, so it might be more typical to have such /32's on a "loopback" interface – `lo` or `dummy0`.)

Comment: Great! If it’s on dummy, the Linux box must have ip forwarding enabled though, right? If it’s on eth0, not, since it’s just an additional address?

Comment: Actually I just realize neither config seems to require `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`. Why is that?

Comment: When it's on eth0, no forwarding is happening as far as your host knows. There is literally no difference in the packet headers between the router having a next-hop route vs an interface route (local subnet route) for this address – the only difference is in which IP address the router tries to ARP *before* the actual delivery – so the host just thinks the router recognized it as a local subnet address.

Comment: As for when it's on dummy0, I *think* that's due to the "Weak host" model that Linux's IPv4 support has chosen – in it, IP addresses belong to the host as a whole, not to any specific interface. (Unlike the "Strong host" model it uses for IPv6, in which addresses *are* interface-bound. On Windows, meanwhile, there's a netsh knob to select one or the other.)

Comment: I see, makes sense. Is the more proper way then as a second address in eth0 or via a dummy interface? Also considering IPv6 will be added as well.

Comment: In your case, I don't really know how you plan on using it – if there's only one network interface, then having the address on the same eth0 (like you originally had) will be simpler. I'd usually go with loopback/dummy, but that's because I usually add such addresses as explicitly belonging to the system, not to any of its connections (e.g. the same /32 could be reached through three different interfaces thanks to OSPF, and it also allows the /32 to remain "up" when some of those interfaces go down).

Comment: Intention is to use the /32 as a “floating/fixed” IP for a DNS server such that I can move the DNS server (VM) easily to different locations (subnet) without having to change the server address. The static route to the /32 will always be distributed by OSPF but the DNS server itself will only ever have that one eth0 interface. It seems to me a dedicated dummy interface is still more elegant in this case. Let me know if you disagree